# "Interface type cannot be statically allocated" on multiple class-type variables after @property

Tags: java, iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm trying to study Objective-C to create an iOS app with it. In Java, we can declare class-type variables in a single line, like this:

```
CustomClass first, second, third;
```

I tried to do the same in my interface in Objective-C using the `@property` tag:

```
@interface Rectangle : NSObject
@property XYPoint* origin, opposite;
// ...
@end
```

But this throws an error "Interface type cannot be statically allocated." However, if I declare the two variables on separate property tags such as below, the error disappears.

```
@interface Rectangle : NSObject
@property XYPoint* origin;
@property XYPoint* opposite;
// ...
@end
```

Why is that? When I use my first approach with primitive types, it works. How come it doesn't for class types? Also, unlike in other Q&As about the same error message, I didn't miss putting the `*` after my type declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
@property XYPoint *origin, *opposite;
```

EDIT: You synthesize them without the star like this:

```
@synthesize origin, opposite;
```

/Søren

Comment: Now I'm getting "Expected a property name in @synthesize." I typed it like this: `@synthesize *origin, *opposite;` Why is that?

Comment: That's a completely different problem.  I'll give you a hint...you synthesize *variables* not *pointers*

Comment: Yup, fixed it. Removed the asterisks. ;)